# SimplePie html rssfeeds Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, simplepie, codeigniter-pagination

I wanted to ask, I have a div that I would want to place RSS feeds from the BBC or CNN. Now that works but I wanted to paginate the feeds that come in, display 5 at a time with the others showing when the links are clicked.

I am starting to write the code now but I was hoping I would get either inspiration or have an example I could glean from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [SimplePie RSS class and CodeIgniter](http://www.nextbigleap.com/index.php/blog/post/simplepie-rss-class-and-codeigniter), also check [SimplePie Plugins and Integration](http://simplepie.org/wiki/plugins/start) and [SimplePie CodeIgniter Library](http://www.haughin.com/code/simplepie/), study more and learn it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Haughin's Simple CodeIgniter Library](http://www.haughin.com/code/simplepie/). It's very simple to use.

```
$this->load->library('simplepie');
$this->simplepie->set_feed_url('http://feeds.haughin.com/haughin');
$this->simplepie->set_cache_location(APPPATH.'cache/rss');
$this->simplepie->init();
$this->simplepie->handle_content_type();

$data['rss_items'] = $this->simplepie->get_items();

echo "<li>";
foreach($rss_items as $item) {
    echo "<li>";
    echo "<a href='" .$item->get_link() . "'>";
    echo $item->get_title();
    echo "</a>";
    echo "</li>";
}
echo "</li>";
```

You can check out the code [here](http://www.haughin.com/code/simplepie/).

Comment: Does anyone know how to take the value of $item->get_title() and add it to a variable? It sounds simple but I all I get is: "Fatal error: Cannot use object of type SimplePie_Item as array in /home/seedetai/public_html/testseedetail/application/models/post_model.php on line 162".